# Trouble with basic calculator using switch

Tags: java, switch-statement, calculator

I have already researched this question, but could not find an answer that solved my problem. I keep on getting output 0. For this assignment, I'm not allowed to use any methods. In my program, 1+2 equals 0

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int result = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number");
    int number = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter operation");
    System.out.println("1.+");
    System.out.println("2.-");
    System.out.println("3.*");
    System.out.println("4./");
    System.out.println("5.=");
    int operation = sc.nextInt();

    while (operation != 5) {
        System.out.println("Enter next number");
        number = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter operation");
        operation = sc.nextInt();

        switch (operation) {
            case 1:
                result += number;
                System.out.println("result= " + result);
                break;
            case 2:
                result -= number;
                System.out.println("result= " + result);
                break;
            case 3:
                result *= number;
                System.out.println("result= " + result);
                break;
            case 4:
                result/ = number;
                System.out.println("result= " + result);
                break;

        }
        System.out.println(result);

    }
```

Comment: What do you do to get 0? Do you always divide by any chance?

Comment: in the case of multiplication as first operation, your result would be 0 since you have used result *= number.

Comment: No I tried it with the basic 1+2.

Comment: There might be a possibility where you are getting int operation issues. For example 4/5 is 0.8, but if you are using integers, it would be "floored", meaning rounded down. Try using doubles as the result and number values

Comment: I don't get 0s; it KINDA works. Logic is a bit off, though; see how you're throwing away the first two inputs? You set number and operation outside the loop, and then set them again within the loop without performing the operation.

Comment: after `int number = sc.nextInt();` in line 5 do `result = number;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.lang.System;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {

    int result = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number");
    result = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter operation");
    System.out.println("1.+");
    System.out.println("2.-");
    System.out.println("3.*");
    System.out.println("4./");
    System.out.println("5.=");
    int operation = sc.nextInt();

    while (operation != 5) {
        System.out.println("Enter next number");
        int number = sc.nextInt();

        switch (operation) {
            case 1:
                result += number;
                System.out.println("result= " + result);
                break;
            case 2:
                result -= number;
                System.out.println("result= " + result);
                break;
            case 3:
                result *= number;
                System.out.println("result= " + result);
                break;
            case 4:
                result /= number;
                System.out.println("result= " + result);
                break;

        }
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("Enter operation");
        operation = sc.nextInt();

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: still getting 0 if I add case 5.  
case 5: System.out.println(result);

Comment: Yes you're right, that wasn't the problem after all (: the code had two problems: The first was it override the number parameter before an operation was actually performed and propagated into result and the second one was operation was overridden at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the meta @chsdk I missed that indentation (;

Answer (score 0):

for the first number and second number you are using the variable number..so u will get Zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your first operation was not being executed.

Try this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int result = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number");
    result = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter operation");
    System.out.println("1.+");
    System.out.println("2.-");
    System.out.println("3.*");
    System.out.println("4./");
    System.out.println("5.=");
    int operation = sc.nextInt();

    while (operation != 5) {
        System.out.println("Enter next number");
        int operand2 = sc.nextInt();

        switch (operation) {
            case 1:
                result += operand2;
                System.out.println("result= " + result);
                break;
            case 2:
                result -= operand2;
                System.out.println("result= " + result);
                break;
            case 3:
                result *= operand2;
                System.out.println("result= " + result);
                break;
            case 4:
                result /= operand2;
                System.out.println("result= " + result);
                break;

        }
        System.out.println("Enter operation");
        operation = sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Global result = " + result);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are reading `number` and `operation` twice for the first iteration of the loop instead move the two reading condition after switch case as given below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    int result = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
    System.out.println("Enter number");
    int number = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter operation");
    System.out.println("1.+");
    System.out.println("2.-");
    System.out.println("3.*");
    System.out.println("4./");
    System.out.println("5.=");
    int operation = sc.nextInt();
    try {
        while (operation != 5) {


            switch (operation) {
                case 1:
                    result += number;
                    System.out.println("result= " + result);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    result -= number;
                    System.out.println("result= " + result);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    result *= number;
                    System.out.println("result= " + result);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    result /= number;
                    System.out.println("result= " + result);
                    break;

            }

            System.out.println("Enter next number");
            number = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter operation");
            operation = sc.nextInt();


        }
        System.out.println("Final esult is " + result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Enter number 2
Enter operation 1
1.+
2.-
3.*
4./
5.=
result= 2
Enter next number 5
Enter operation 5
Final result is 2
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/ipaqVy)